# How to resolve unresolved dependency (with another/latest version perhaps)?

Tags: sbt

Apparently the version of a transitive dependency within my sbt project has been bumped - but the direct dependency has not "caught up" with that change.

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.sf.py4j#py4j;0.7: not found
```

The updated (and only available) version is 0.8  (why did they do that is another question.. )

I have attempted to remedy this temporarily by installing the new version into my local maven repo under the old version number of 0.7 - in order to attempt to mollify the dependent library.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file  \
-Dfile=c:\shared\py4j-0.8.1.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.py4j  -DartifactId=py4j -Dversion=version=0.7 -Dpackaging=jar
```

However, when running sbt yet again, the same error persists.  So I need another strategy for dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about declaring the new version as the dependency in your build and [`force` it](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#forcing-a-revision) (but *guess* you won't need it as "[By default, the latest revision is selected](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#conflict-management)")?

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.py4j" % "py4j" % "0.8" force()
```

It assumes you've your local Maven repository set up in `resolvers` - see [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#resolvers):

> sbt can search your local Maven repository if you add it as a
>   repository:
>
> ```
> resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
> ```

Comment: Thx for pointing these out!  I have set up the local resolver incorrectly. After fixing I will report back (and if appropriate award)

Comment: The "file://" does not work on windows, i used the following instead: resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal